# Stretch textfloatsep instead of parskip to align columns to the bottom of the page

Tags: spacing, floats, multicol

I have a large float on top of two-column text (with `multicols`), with a new paragraph in the second column. Before the second paragraph, `parskip` gets stretched to align the baseline of the second column with the end of the text area. However, this leaves the baseline of the first column unaligned.

Consider the following MWE*:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\hrule
\vskip+13cm
\hrule
\caption{The figure caption.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

<sub>* I use the `twocolumn` option to set up the column width and sep</sub>

[image: actual result]

How can I tell LaTeX to stretch the white space between the float and the text to align both baselines? Increasing the glue on `textfloatsep` / `dbltextfloatsep` did not help.

I can achieve the desired effect by placing `\vskip+10.4pt` before `\end{figure}`, but this requires fiddling:

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you ignored the warning **Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option ...**

Delete the `twocolumn` option to the class and the `\onecolum` at the start of the document and everything looks good to me.

```
% multicolprob2.tex SE 625032

\documentclass%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%[twocolumn]
  {article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\onecolumn
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\hrule
\vskip+13cm
\hrule
\caption{The figure caption.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to change the document's layout then use the `geometry` package not the `twocolumn` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. Removing twocolumn and onecolumn in this case just reduces the width of the columns and hides the problem. Simply adding `\usepackage{geometry}` without even specifying anything else widens the columns and makes the issue reappear.

Comment: @Vertho I found that if you put `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` just after the `\begin{multicols}{2}` seemed to solve your problem. I have no idea why as I am not expert in `multicol`. That fixed your problem but I added lots more text and on the last page the last paragraph had a space before it to make the two columns end at the same vertical position. So, perhaps it is to do with balancing the columns. Perhaps the creator of `multicol` could give some advice, if asked.

Comment: Thanks for investigating! The issue with removing the glue from `parskip` is that the columns are no longer flush to the bottom of the page. Thus, although the baselines of the two neighboring columns are aligned with this approach, they would not be aligned to the bottom of the columns on the opposite page (provided they fill the page). There should be "one more line there" in the space that is occupied by the stretched `parskip` in my initial picture, but it is not quite large enough, and in the left column, there is no `parskip` to stretch, so the column ends up shorter.